# Find Taylor expansion of $f(x)=\ln{1-x^2\over 1+x^2}$, and then find radius of convergence.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Find Taylor expansion of $f(x)=\ln{1-x^2\over 1+x^2}$, and then find radius of convergence. My problem here is the Taylor series. Computing the few first derivative is possible, but I can't seem to have caught any pattern I can formulate elegantly. Maybe I should only make an observation about the derivatives without using a formula? I could really use any help here.

**Edit:** I arrived at: $$f(x)=-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^{2+4n}\over 2n+1}$$. Using the ratio test: $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}|{a_{n+1}\over a_n}|=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}|{{x^2x^{4n}x^4\over 2n+3}\over {x^2x^{4n}\over 2n+1}}|=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}|{x^4(2n+1)\over 2n+3}|=|x^4|$$. $|x^4|<1\iff |x|<1 \Rightarrow R=1$.

Comment: Write down the expansion of $\ln(1-x^2)$, of $\ln(1+x^2)$, and subtract.  For $\ln(1+x^2)$, write down the series for $\ln(1+t)$ and replace $t$ by $x^2$.

Comment: Great idea, thank you.

Comment: @Meitar: $|x| < 1$.

Comment: Final answers are of no help, sorry. But thank you for finding out.

Comment: @Meitar, you can use this: $(\ln\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2})'=-\frac{4x}{1-x^4}$. Expansion of $1/(1-x^4)$ is trivially.

Comment: What happens when we do Complex Analysis? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outline: Write down the Maclaurin expansion of $\ln(1-x^2)$, of $\ln(1+x^2)$, and subtract term by term.  For $\ln(1+x^2)$, write down the series for $\ln(1+t)$ and replace $t$ by $x^2$.

The radius of convergence can be found in one of the usual ways, for example by using the Ratio Test.

Comment: Thank you @André . I edited my question. Can you confirm what I did is correct?

Comment: How does tagging work here? I think I did it wrong..

Comment: Do you mean the tags calculus and so on? The last two tags seem appropriate, *calculus* and *real analysis* not so much. Your edited solution is fine.

Comment: Those two tags are the main name of my course. 
I was talking about tagging people so as to address a reply to them, though. Thank you for your help and your evaluation.

Comment: Every comment under an answer gets automatically sent to the answerer. I did not reply immediately because I was offline, aka asleep.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Taylor series for $\ln(1+u)$ and $\ln(1-u)$ and subsitute  $x^2$ to $u$:
\begin{align*}
\ln(1-x^2)&=-x^2-\dfrac{x^4}2-\dfrac{x^6}3-\dotsm - \dfrac{x^{2n}}{n}-\dotsm\\
\ln(1+x^2)&=x^2-\dfrac{x^4}2+\dfrac{x^6}3-\dotsm +(-1)^{n-1} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{n}+\dotsm
\end{align*}
We obtain:
$$\ln\dfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=\ln(1-x^2)-\ln(1+x^2)=-2\Bigl(x^2+\frac{x^6}3+\dots+\dfrac{x^{2(2k+1)}}{2k+1}+\dotsm\Bigr)$$

*Radius of convergence:* The function is defined on $(-1,1)$, and the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $\ln(1\pm u)$ is $1$. Hence the radius of convergence for the Taylor series of $f(x)$ is $1$.