# What is the Taylor series of $\ln \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion

> What is the Taylor series of $$\ln \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$$
>   ?

I started by evaluating the first derivatives but the more I go, the more complicated they are and I can't identify a pattern.

Comment: It's better to parse it on two parts.

Comment: What is the centre of the Taylor series that you desire?

Comment: @AlanWang, around $x=0$.

Comment: @openspace, that's a good idea actually.

Comment: Hint: $\ln(\frac{a}{b}) = \ln(a) - \ln (b)$.

Comment: In your book you will find expansion for  $log(1+x)$. Replace $x$ by $\pm x^2$ and use properties of $\ln$.

Comment: @Maesumi, awesome idea!

Comment: See also: [Find Taylor expansion of $f(x)=\ln{1-x^2\over 1+x^2}$, and then find radius of convergence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1340985#1340989)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint 1* consider $$\ln(1-x^{2})+\ln(1+x^{2})$$
*Hint 2* consider $$(1-x^{2}) = (1-x)(1+x)$$
and $$1+x^{2}= (1-ix)(1+ix)$$

Comment: It should be $\ln(1-x^2)-\ln(1+x^2)$ for the quotient, and you can use the logarithm series directly from this form, no further factorization required.

Comment: @LutzL yes, miss the "-"

Answer (score 3):

As $\log\dfrac ab=\log a-\log b$

$$\ln\dfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=\ln(1-x^2)-\ln(1+x^2)$$

Now use $\ln(1-u)=-\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{u^r}r$ as $-1\le u<1$

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $\log\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$ is:
$$ \frac{4x}{x^4-1} = -4x-4x^5-4x^9-\ldots = -4\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{1+4n} \tag{1}$$
hence it follows that:
$$ \log\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right) = -4\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{4n+2}}{4n+2} = -2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{4n+2}}{2n+1}.\tag{2}$$
You may also notice that $\log\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=-2\,\text{arctanh}(x^2)$.

Comment: Very nice solution!